# Cordova build errors out

Tags: android, firebase, cordova

I have been trying to build this Cordova application for several days now and can't get this to work. It keeps erroring out with the same error about firebase. Cordova Version: cordova --version 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1). Gradle: distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

I have tried deleting all the plugins before building. I have tried removing android and ios platforms and re-adding them. I have tried modifying the build.gradle file and the project.properties file. Nothing works.

```
D:\billaway\mobile\freeup\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginInstanceIDService.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
public class FirebasePluginInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
                                                     ^
  symbol: class FirebaseInstanceIdService
D:\billaway\mobile\freeup\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
                  ^
  symbol:   class NotificationChannel
  location: package android.app
D:\billaway\mobile\freeup\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\tapjoy\TapjoyPlugin.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
import org.apache.cordova.PermissionHelper;
                         ^
  symbol:   class PermissionHelper
  location: package org.apache.cordova
D:\billaway\mobile\freeup\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginInstanceIDService.java:16: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
D:\billaway\mobile\freeup\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:187: error: cannot find symbol
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable O
  location: class VERSION_CODES
D:\billaway\mobile\freeup\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:188: error: cannot find symbol
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                ^
  symbol:   class NotificationChannel
  location: class FirebasePluginMessagingService
D:\billaway\mobile\freeup\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:188: error: cannot find symbol
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class NotificationChannel
  location: class FirebasePluginMessagingService
D:\billaway\mobile\freeup\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\tapjoy\TapjoyPlugin.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
                PermissionHelper.requestPermissions(this, 0, permissions);
                ^
  symbol:   variable PermissionHelper
  location: class TapjoyPlugin
D:\billaway\mobile\freeup\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\tapjoy\TapjoyPlugin.java:368: error: cannot find symbol
            if(!PermissionHelper.hasPermission(this, p))
                ^
  symbol:   variable PermissionHelper
  location: class TapjoyPlugin
D:\billaway\mobile\freeup\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\tapjoy\TapjoyPlugin.java:383: error: cannot find symbol
        PermissionHelper.requestPermissions(this, requestCode, permissions);
        ^
  symbol:   variable PermissionHelper
  location: class TapjoyPlugin
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
10 errors
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
FAILED

BUILD FAILED
```

Here is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.freeup.rewards" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Rewards</name>
    <description>
        Earn credits for free mobile service when you share your opinion and fill out surveys
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://billawayglobal.com">
        Billaway Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.7.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-market" spec="https://github.com/xmartlabs/cordova-plugin-market" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-tapjoy" spec="~1.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-tapjoyba" spec="https://github.com/billAway/TapjoyCordova.git" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="^2.5.0" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Need more info here... Do you use any framework? What is your Cordova version? Graddle version? Paste your config.xml...

Comment: I edited it with the requested information. Gradle version is 2.14.1, Cordova is 9.0.0. I don't think we use any frameworks. I inherited this mess with no turnover, according to them it was supposed to just build.

Comment: Did you add cordova firebase plugin to your app?

Comment: Yes. I added it. Also removed it and re-added it, without any luck

Comment: OK I see.. Most plugins and stuff aren't compatible past Cordova 7.1 due to changes. My best advice right now is to uninstall cordova 9 and try again with 7.1.

Comment: Removed 9.0 and installed 7.1. Removed android platform and installed android@6.0.0. Received the same error.